# Why our life on Earth defines our future life in eternity?

Tags: afterlife, eternal-life

Why our limited knowledge of God or of our sins defines our future life in eternity. Isn't it little bit unfair?
I understand if the angels falls into hell after they make a decision not to serve God. They have full knowledge so they know what they are doing.

But us, people we don't even know what is love so why this life should decide if we choose God in the next life?

I saw some NDE videos and people mostly claimed that they had the same way of thinking as on Earth when they were judged and they recognized their sinfulness. And with this way of thinking rejected or accepted God. Isn't this little unfair that our eternity will be decided by our limited way of thinking here on Earth?
Thanks

Comment: It is worth noting that not all Christian traditions hold that you have to decide in this life, some hold you can decide at judgement, still more hold that if you would decide at judgement to follow after God, you would also do so in this life as God reveals himself sufficiently for his power and Truth to be known.

Comment: well, I meant you decide in the next life but based of your earthly way of thinking...

Comment: Personally, my impression is that those who choose to reject God will do so in as full of a knowledge of God as the angels have and continue to rebel.  Our sinful state of rebellion is indifferent to the character, power or justice of God.

Comment: But why would we reject God if we will fully know him? What could that be in us that one accepts him and other rejects him if it's not taken from our earthly life experiences?

Comment: why do some angels reject him and others don't?  People have free will.  We get to choose to follow God or not.  Some people believe they have it together and don't need God and will still feel they are better off doing their own thing.  There are literally infinitely many possible reasons why someone could choose their own will over God's.

Comment: can a newborn baby reject God? I don't think so. So our decision to reject God would be based of our life experience or emotions. I don't think this is good enough to reject God. Not sure why would angels choose hell if they know exactly what they are choosing. It doesn't make sense to me. Saying it's free will doesn't fully explains it because our free will is expressed in what we know or how we feel and what we believe is true...

Comment: I would posit that a newborn baby could reject God as they still have a character and will, though we are drifting off topic and in to a discussion in comments.  If you'd like to have more of a discussion, I suggest you join us in chat once you hit sufficient reputation on the site (which usually happens pretty quick.)

Comment: never heard of a newborn baby going to hell. Anyway, I'll wait until I have enough reputation...

Comment: I have a friend that thinks that ALL people need to willingly accept Christ to be saved; babies included.  This being said and with all the comments above, this question is going to have WAY to many opinionated answers from too many different point of views.  I think you should rephrase your question.

Comment: Here are some links that may help you out based on the issue on salvation:http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/do-i-get-a-second-chance-to-believe-in-jesus-after-i-die ///
http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18582/is-there-a-biblical-basis-for-believing-someone-can-be-saved-after-dying-and-goi ///
http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/what-happens-to-people-who-have-never-heard-about-jesus /// http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30034/can-someone-go-to-heaven-even-when-not-believing-in-god

Comment: after reading all the comments, it looks like everyone is referring, suggesting or wishing there was something that helps our earthly thinking to be purified after death.